# How to update attributes without validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've got a model with its validations, and I found out that I can't update an attribute without validating the object before.

I already tried to add `on => :create` syntax at the end of each validation line, but I got the same results.

My announcement model have the following validations:

```
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :announcement_type_id

  validate :validates_publication_date
  validate :validates_start_date
  validate :validates_start_end_dates
  validate :validates_category
  validate :validates_province

  validates_length_of :title, :in => 6..255, :on => :save
  validates_length_of :subtitle, :in => 0..255, :on => :save
  validates_length_of :subtitle, :in => 0..255, :on => :save
  validates_length_of :place, :in => 0..50, :on => :save

  validates_numericality_of :vacants, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0,  :only_integer => true
  validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0,  :only_integer => true
```

My rake task does the following:

```
  task :announcements_expiration => :environment do
    announcements = Announcement.expired

    announcements.each do |a|
      #Gets the user that owns the announcement
      user = User.find(a.user_id)
      puts a.title + '...'

      a.state = 'deactivated'

      if a.update_attributes(:state => a.state)
        puts 'state changed to deactivated'
      else
        a.errors.each do |e|
          puts e
        end

      end
    end
```

This throws all the validation exceptions for that model, in the output.

Does anybody how to update an attribute without validating the model?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

USE [update_attribute](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute) instead of [update_attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes)

Updates a single attribute and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure.

```
if a.update_attribute('state', a.state)
```

Note:- 'update_attribute' update only one attribute at a time from the code given in question i think it will work for you.

Comment: You can use save(false) without validation

Comment: Hmm, but is there a way that still parses out params[:instance] like update_attributes does?

Comment: `update_attribute` is deprecated in Rails 4, FYI. Try using a.attributes({ ... }).save(false) instead. Or if you don't care (or want) callbacks to be run, checkout `update_column`.

Comment: For Rails 4, `save(false)` doesn't work, you must use `save(validate: false)`

Comment: @JoshPinter Hm, `update_attribute` doesn't seem to be deprecated in Rails 4.2 (it is aliased as `update_column`): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute

Comment: @TončiD. Wow, you are absolutely correct. It looks like they intended to deprecate it in 3.2 and remove it in 4.0 but then decided to reverse their decision since it was not interchangeable with `update_column`. A lot can change in two years! :) Thanks for pointing it out. Read more about it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/rubyonrails-core/BWPUTK7WvYA

Comment: `update_attributes` was deprecated in Rails 6.0 and removed in Rails 6.1.

Answer (score 246):

You can do something like:

```rb
object.attribute = value
object.save(validate: false)
```

Comment: actually its object.save(:validate => false)

Comment: `object.attributes = hash` is a little more in line with the question. If anyone wonders, `update_attributes(hash)` itself merely does `self.attributes = hash; save`.

Comment: object.save(false) is all that will work if using Rails 2 and below

Comment: This is better because it would still execute the callbacks that update timestamps. The op specifically mentions avoiding validations, not ALL callbacks.

Comment: By doing this, it is also much clearer to the next developer that the validations are explicitly not wanted

Comment: You can also use `.tap` if you want to do it on 1 line of code: `object.tap { |o| o.attribute = value }.save(validate: false)`

Comment: Just curious, how can this be used to skip only a particular validation in the case when you dont want to skip everything?

Answer (score 103):

try using

```
@record.assign_attributes({ ... })
@record.save(validate: false)
```

works for me

Comment: this is the valid answer with Rails 4, a combination of all the comments to the currently accepted answer.

Comment: `@record.tap { |r| r.assign_attributes({ ... }) }.save(validate: false)` does it on 1 line of code if you prefer.

Answer (score 50):

Yo can use:

```
a.update_column :state, a.state
```

Check: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column

> Updates a single attribute of an object, without calling save.

Comment: This is the best approach if you want to skip both validations and callbacks. There is also `update_columns` if you're looking to update multiple attributes.

Answer (score 10):

All the validation from model are skipped when we use `validate: false`

```
user = User.new(....)
user.save(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
validates_length_of :title, :in => 6..255, :on => :create
```

so it only works during create?

Comment: The OP said: `I already tried to add on => :create syntax at the end of each validation line, but I got the same results.`