# Possible to skip validations on update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This seems like a silly problem but I can't find the answer anywhere!

Is it possible to `update_attributes()` and skip validations, like in `save(validate: false)`?

I have a long form with some lengthy `text` (not `string`) fields, and I'd like to offer the user the ability to save their progress on the form. Normally, I want length minimums, etc, on the answers before they're able to submit it and move on, but in the case where they're just clicking "Save" I'd like to put whatever progress they've made in the database so they can come back and finish later. Is there a way to skip the validations in this case?

From looking around, it seems the only thing I can do is enumerate each field individually like so:

```
@obj.field1 = ...
@obj.field2 = ...
@obj.field3 = ...
...
@obj.save(:validate => false)
```

Is that really the case? I'd be worried about adding another field at some point in the future and forgetting to update the controller here.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998780/how-to-update-attributes-without-validation) if you're only updating one attribute.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@obj.attributes = params[:obj]
@obj.save(false)
```

**Update for Rails 3**

```
@obj.attributes = params[:obj]
@obj.save(:validate => false)
```

Comment: it should be @obj.save(validate:false)

Comment: Can this be done with only a certain validation @thekindofme ?

Comment: @MarcoPrins not sure about that.

Comment: @obj.save(:validate => false) is not depreciated in rails 3 or 4, afaik, and some find rockets more readable than colons.  Let's hope more working code is not invalidated by forced, 'new-syntax updates' any time soon.

Comment: Is it possible to skip validation of only some columns with update_attributes ? because I need to update only few columns, can you suggest me some idea ?